# any possible window.TWTR browser issues

Tags: twitter

for the window.TWTR object, is there any browser support limitation issue on this?

i.e like, will IE 9, 10 Chrome all support this?

Please advise

Comment: also, when i do alert(window.TWTR); it is undefined. what is the work around for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct, it is undefined. it is better to just use this from twitter, suggested by twitter

```
   window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

The above prevents widgets.js loading twice